# keyboard not showing every time

Tags: android, keyboard

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (v == etpw2) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw2.getText().toString())) {
                    etpw2.setEnabled(false);
                    etpw2.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                    etpw1.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                    etpw1.requestFocus();
                    etpw1.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        } else if (v == etpw3) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw3.getText().toString())) {
                    etpw3.setEnabled(false);
                    etpw3.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                    etpw2.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                    etpw2.requestFocus();
                    etpw2.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        } else if (v == etpw4) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw4.getText().toString())) {
                    etpw4.setEnabled(false);
                    etpw4.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                    etpw3.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                    etpw3.requestFocus();
                    etpw3.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        } else if (v == etpw5) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw5.getText().toString())) {
                    etpw5.setEnabled(false);
                    etpw5.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                    etpw4.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                    etpw4.requestFocus();
                    etpw4.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        } else if (v == etpw6) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw6.getText().toString())) {
                    etpw6.setEnabled(false);
                    etpw6.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                    etpw5.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                    etpw5.requestFocus();
                    etpw5.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I used this for for deleting word, but as I press keyboard erase button, keyboard automatically closes.

I want keyboard open every time. But now it hide the keyboard when keyboard's back button is pressed.

Please help me out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'OnKey' callback method will not be triggered for soft keyboard with editable controls.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener

Hope you managed to get the 'OnKey' call back method for text field.

If you disable any text field, it make the keyboard to dismiss. So, in below code delete the line 'etpw2.setEnabled(false);'. So, it keeps keyboard presented.

```
if (v == etpw2) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etpw2.getText().toString())) {
                etpw2.setEnabled(false);
                etpw2.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_blackborder));
                etpw1.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_orangeborder));
                etpw1.requestFocus();
                etpw1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```